# How to install JavaFX in Eclipse 2023-03

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have tried everything I can find, help install new software and given the Oxygen link, selecting e(fx)clipse and installing, adding the external jars to the build path, duplicating my JRE and including the javafx files, everything I can find says to find jfsrt in <JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib but that doesn't exist there. I've been trying for hours to fix the imports so I can import JavaFX classes but Eclipse just refuses. Please, explain this to me like I am a fifth grader, I cannot figure out for the life of me what to do.

I already explained what I did.

Comment: I know you think you explained what you did, but your description is both vague and unorganized. You should indicate what **exactly** you did, step by step. As you already know, there are tons of tutorials on how to do exactly what you need. Which tutorial did you use, and where does it go wrong? No one can help you without specific details, and no one is going to custom write a tutorial just for you when there are many out there already.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging that I at least think I've explained what I did. I've just been at a complete dead end for a week now, i'm something like 40 - 50 hours in on solutions that don't work on their faces and coming up with an exhaustive list of what I've tried would be both impossible and unhelpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUbORGu-z6Q I have recently followed this... and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz8P528uGjk both, most of what I've done has been along these lines and everyone claims this should work. Is the problem perhaps that the package wasn't started as a JFX project?

Comment: So I know what I did wrong, and thank you SO MUCH for your patience Mars, and for not just telling me I'm bad at providing details. So the problem I ran into is that my module-info.java didn't include
`requires javafx.controls;
opens com.packagename to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;`

So that's definitely on me! I knew I was doing something stupid just didn't know where ti was.

Comment: I have found that often those who try YouTube videos to learn JavaFX often can’t get started with JavaFX development, unlike those that follow the official [getting started instructions at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: That was where I started. Like I said after dozens of hours trying to solve the problem and fix it, an exhaustive list of everything I'd followed would neither be possible, nor helpful. And those getting started instructions mention nothing about the module info file, so even if I hadn't followed those official instructions first, directing me to them would have been no more helpful than any of the youtube videos. I do appreciate the time, but since you saw the solution you must know that the problem wasn't in those instructions. So what was the point of this comment?

Comment: The question is "How to install JavaFX in Eclipse 2023-03", the answer is to follow the [getting started instructions at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  StackOverflow doesn't recommend posting link-only answers.  I commented so that if somebody searches for "How to install JavaFX in Eclipse", they can find a reference to the recommended solution.  I understand that you did not find the answer you were seeking in that resource.  Nevertheless, the official instructions are a good starting place for many developers IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was running into is that the package didn't include the requirement for javafx in the module-info.java file, adding

```
requires javafx.controls;
opens com.packagename to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
```

solved the problem. Just adding the files to the buildpath did nothing without changing that file.

Comment: You don’t need to open to `javafx.fxml` if you aren’t using fxml.  And if you are using fxml, then you need to `requires javafx.fxml;` as shown in the [openjfx modular sample code](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Maven/hellofx/src/main/java/module-info.java).  Also I fixed formatting, as the code was formatted as executable JavaScript/html, which it is not.